# Return One value if more than one Exsist

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

if i have same values in a column and i want to return only one instead of all of them what would be a method.

```
ArrayList<String> getAllNotes() {
    Cursor cursor;
    mDbHelper = mSqliteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + SqliteHelpers.TABLE_NAME;
    cursor = mDbHelper.rawQuery(query, null);
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String itemname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SqliteHelpers.NOTES_COLUMN));
        if (itemname != null) {
            arrayList.add(itemname);
        }
    }
    return arrayList;
}
```

As you can see in image there are four items all are same but i want one tobe return other will be returned normal. except more than one.[image](http://ibin.co/25Ss6rosHCcn)

Comment: Just replace your while by an if statement.

Comment: sqlite -> `limit 1` in your query. or `distinct(whatever)`. Not clear which would suit, based on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return the column you want:

```
ArrayList<String> getAllNotes() {
Cursor cursor;
mDbHelper = mSqliteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
String query = "SELECT Distinct NOTES_COLUMN FROM " + SqliteHelpers.TABLE_NAME;
cursor = mDbHelper.rawQuery(query, null);
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String itemname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SqliteHelpers.NOTES_COLUMN));
    if (itemname != null) {
        arrayList.add(itemname);
    }
}
return arrayList;
}
```